# Does effective mass of a hole / electron in a semiconductor change with temperature?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

I had a slightly different question here before but I've boiled it down to this:

Are the effective masses $m_e^*$ and $m_h^*$ of electrons and holes in a semiconductor constant w.r.t. temperature?

Answer (score 3):

The effective masses for holes and electrons are not constant when the temperature changes. These effective masses are related to the curvatures (second derivatives) of the energy-wave vector dispersion relations at minima and maxima of the conduction band and valence bands, respectively. These dispersion relations and band gaps change with temperature. In silicon, the effective masses show a slight increase with temperature.